# Windows 10 Start Menu Searches No Longer Show File Details

Tags: windows-10, search, start-menu, productivity

Just a day or two ago when I searched for a file or folder with the Windows 10 start menu it would come up with a double column panel of the search results.

On the left it had a list of "matches" and on the right it would show some details about the thing you had your mouse over, such as (if I recall correctly) the full path of the file and a link to open it's containing folder in the file explorer, which I found incredibly handy. (I know you can right-click & "open file location" but that's just not the same.)

Right now when I search I only see the normal left column, no extra details, even when searching an exact file name.

It there a way to re-enable this functionality? I've made no changes to Windows 10 settings as far as I know.

Comment: This seems linked to : https://superuser.com/q/1359291/58658 However, I am not sure there is an actual option to control it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if my suggestion can help you on the issue. But it could be helpful.

1. Restart the `windows search` services in the **services.msc**
2. Restart the **Cortana** in the **Task manager**

Or `reinstall` and `re-register` the **Cortana**.

You can follow the link.
[How to Reinstall and Re-register Cortana in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/96116-reinstall-re-register-cortana-windows-10-a.html)