# Enable/disable windows 10 start menu search with additional options pane

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, windows-search

Recently I did an upgrade to my windows 10 PC and got the new 1803 update. Along with that I received a new start menu search screen that appeared a couple of weeks after the update that will show more information on what I was search for. It adds an extra pane on the right hand side that gives me more options. These options appear to be the same ones as if I would have right clicked the search listing.

*Image for reference*
[image: Windows 10 Start Menu Search with more options]

My coworker tried to set this up himself but we could not find this setting at all. Does anyone know what setting changes the start menu search in windows 10 to get this extra pane on the right?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would like to know where this setting is also, so I can remove it.

Comment: @Fluinc I am pretty sure it is an Windows update 1809 feature. I enjoy it, but hey ... to each his own!

Comment: Does anyone know how to disable it yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure this is a Windows 10 1809 feature. It went away with the rollback, and now it has returned after I did a manual update.