# How do I get the second panel back in Windows search?

Tags: windows, windows-10, search, start-menu

I recently upgraded to Windows 10 Pro. Among other features I noticed that now when I search for things from the start menu like applications another panel that I wasn't seeing before appears. It's similar to the second panel that shows up when you do a web search from the start menu but it displays buttons such as run as administrator that were previously only available via right click. I found it immensely useful.

But a few restarts later that panel stopped appearing and it hasn't since. I didn't know what the panel is called, so I couldn't Google it. Does anyone here know what I'm talking about and at least tell me what it's called? Even better would be telling me if and how I can get it back.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit to be more clear:**

1. The options that showed up were not exactly what shows up in the right click menu, there were just similarities. Options included run as administrator and i think open file location.
2. They showed up in a panel to the right of the search results and were the same width and height.
3. I was searching from the start menu for applications.

Comment: So the menu that normally only comes up when you right-click was coming up... when?

Comment: @music2myear 1) It wasn’t the exact same menu; it just had some of the same options, and 2) it came up when I searched for applications.

Comment: Where did it show in the UI?

Comment: @music2myear In a panel to the right of where the search results were, the same height and width.

Comment: What other options were in the menu? Also, please use the EDIT button below your question to add this and all other relevant information to the body of the question itself. The goal is that all information necessary to find and answer to your question is in the question itself. Comments are considered temporary.

Comment: @music2myear I feel like I’ve already specified this information in my question, but I’ll edit it to be more clear.

Comment: @music2myear Edited.

Comment: I'm sorry to say this, but could you be Even More Clear? This happened when you upgraded from Win <10 to 10, or 10 Home to Pro? And when you 'search for things', do you right click on the Win Icon or..? So when you say 'the options that showed up', I'd like to know how you got there.

Comment: @reben I upgraded from Windows 10 Home to Windows 10 Pro. By searching I mean using Cortana search.

Comment: Hi. You are either hit by the changes done by Windows Update, OR; - When you choose Search from the Right Click and get Cortana, do you miss the 'Type here to search' at the bottom, or is it still there? If it's there, and you do a search, you get the search results? Can you then do a right click and get Run as Admin and Open File Location ? -- Along this path, where does it 'fail'?

Comment: I believe this user is referring to the panel next to the search as shown in the image on this question. https://superuser.com/questions/1359291/enable-disable-windows-10-start-menu-search-with-additional-options-pane

Comment: Kk, I'm flagging as a dupe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable/disable windows 10 start menu search with additional options pane](https://superuser.com/questions/1359291/enable-disable-windows-10-start-menu-search-with-additional-options-pane)